# nifi extractText Processor issue

Tags: apache-nifi

I am trying to read lines from splitText processor and applying regex to filter rows. However, data is queued before SplitText and not going inside ExtractText Processor. Below are the snapshots of regex (where I am filter out those rows which have 18th filed value in (BT, CV7,CV30) but it never reaches to that point.

In fact the extractText processor does not even start or gets deleted. Its stuck

[image]

and the snapshot of ExtractText settings
[image]

Comment: Hi @omer. What is the "Scheduling" of the ExtractText Processor?

Comment: Hi @omer. Few other questions: 1/Did you validate your regular expression with the content of a queued flowFile? 2/Can you confirm the "matched" relation in the ExtractText Processor is an "Automatically Terminate Relationship"?

Comment: Hi @ValBonn Schedule is time driven and run schedule is set to 0 seconds. Yes I confirm that matched relation is an  "Automatically Terminate Relationship". For the validation of regex, I copied these from a hortonworks tutorial but the issue I see here is that data is not entering into ExtractText  processor rather its queued up.

Comment: Btwn I am using nifi 1.0

Comment: Is it possible for you to share sample data?

Comment: UGW,hxca06,,01061804162357260004,7sdfd,20180416235726+0300,slair02,63338747,20180416235726+0300,30,0,BalTransferReceive,BalTransferReceive,1000.000000,xx,,,2,BT,BT,,,7735709747,ss,7735709747,0,,0,0,0,0,1023,983,20160308,0,,,1,7716745529,,,,,,,0,0,0,0,,0,,
UGW,slair02,,271925004505992,,20180416235726+0300,slair02,63338748,20180416235726+0300,7,1,,,10000.000000,xx,,,2,,V10,50307578072,V10,7739354262,ss,sdaa,,0,0,0,0,1023,983,20170804,0,,,1,,,,,,9751191418256,,0,0,0,0,,2,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is definitively something wrong with your Regular Expression. I cannot point exactly what is wrong, but your example blocked my NiFi :)  I cannot stop/start my ExtractText processor, I cannot purge the incoming queue. We could already guess that on your screenshot, with the "Active Tasks" icon which is visible.

Nevertheless, I think I achieved what you tried to do with these regular expressions :

```
(?:[^\,]*\,){18}BT
(?:[^\,]*\,){18}CV7
(?:[^\,]*\,){18}CV30
```

The lines that contain `BT`, `CV7` or `CV30` at the expected position will be routed to the `matched` relation.

Comment: Thanks @Val .. I got these regex from a tutorial and faced issue while validating through online validators. Can you please share a good online regex validator ?

Comment: Hi @omer. I have no favorite online validator. I tried your one on https://www.freeformatter.com/java-regex-tester.html and on http://www.regexplanet.com/advanced/java/index.html